# Finding a solution when there are two piecewise functions at play

Tags: equation-solving, piecewise

The goal is to mathematically figure out where is the point when the both of the diagrams are the same distance to the Y-axis.

The solution to such a problem can be obtain quite easily by just plotting the diagram and visually inspecting where there are equal distances to the left-hand plot and to the right-hand plot (of course with some error). But I wish to go to the next level, and find the exact value.

Currently I am stuck with NSolve and can't make the final step ...

```
(*points for the lefthand diagram*)
v1 = {0, 170};
v2 = {-3.33, 125.6};
v3 = {-4.548, 114};
v4 = {-14.371, 95};
v5 = {-20.551, 80};
v6 = {-22.651, 74};
v7 = {-27.3475, 27.5};
(*points for the righthand diagram*)
p1 = {17.0445, 170};
p2 = {17.0295, 169.9};
p3 = {14.6615, 168.3};
p4 = {11.6015, 153};
p5 = {10.252, 126.01};
p6 = {2.05, 85};
p7 = {1.8, 80};
p8 = {0, 20};
(*linear functions for the lefthand diagram*)
vv1 = LinearModelFit[{v1, v2}, {1, x}, x];
vv2 = LinearModelFit[{v2, v3}, {1, x}, x];
vv3 = LinearModelFit[{v3, v4}, {1, x}, x];
vv4 = LinearModelFit[{v4, v5}, {1, x}, x];
vv5 = LinearModelFit[{v5, v6}, {1, x}, x];
vv6 = LinearModelFit[{v6, v7}, {1, x}, x];
(*linear functions for the righthand diagram*)
pp1 = LinearModelFit[{p1, p2}, {1, x}, x];
pp2 = LinearModelFit[{p2, p3}, {1, x}, x];
pp3 = LinearModelFit[{p3, p4}, {1, x}, x];
pp4 = LinearModelFit[{p4, p5}, {1, x}, x];
pp5 = LinearModelFit[{p5, p6}, {1, x}, x];
pp6 = LinearModelFit[{p6, p7}, {1, x}, x];
pp7 = LinearModelFit[{p7, p8}, {1, x}, x];

a[x_] := Piecewise[{{vv1[x], -3.33 <= x <= 0}, {vv2[x], -4.548 <= 
      x <= -3.33}, {vv3[x], -14.371 <= x <= -4.548}, {vv4[
      x], -20.551 <= x <= -14.371}, {vv5[x], -22.651 <= 
      x <= -20.551}, {vv6[x], -27.3475 <= x <= -22.651}}];

b[x_] := Piecewise[{{pp1[x], 17.0295 <= x <= 17.0445}, {pp2[x], 
     14.6615 <= x <= 17.0295}, {pp3[x], 
     11.6015 <= x <= 14.6615}, {pp4[x], 
     10.252 <= x <= 11.6015}, {pp5[x], 2.05 <= x <= 10.252}, {pp6[x], 
     1.8 <= x <= 2.05}, {pp7[x], 0 <= x <= 1.8}}];

Plot[{a[x], b[x]}, {x, -30, 30}] 

NSolve[Abs[a[x]] == b[x], x]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get result as follows:

```
Reduce[a[-x] == b[x], x] // Quiet

(*x < 0 || x == 6.92894 || x > 27.3475*)
```

you can see that the logical solution is `6.93`. to get that exactly use:

```
sol = x /. Solve[{a[-x] == b[x], 0 < x < 20}, x][[1]] // Quiet
(*6.92894*)
```

or

```
sol = x /. FindRoot[a[-x] == b[x], {x, 6}]
(*6.92894*)
```

to visualize the solution:

```
Plot[{a[x], b[x], a[-sol]}, {x, -30, 30}, Exclusions -> None, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[0.02], Point[{{-sol, a[-sol]}, {sol, b[sol]}}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what i am looking for. Thank you!